# Git recover deleted files before any commit

Tags: git

I've just started a new repository that had some files already, then I did `git add .` but after that i did `git rm -r -f ./` and that deleted all the files. Is there any way to get them back? I didn't do any commit before that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748090/how-to-recover-files-from-missing-tree-and-dangling-blobs

Comment: Nope. No commit = no history. Sorry for your loss

Comment: Ok then, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover files from missing tree and dangling blobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748090/how-to-recover-files-from-missing-tree-and-dangling-blobs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All staged, but uncommitted, files deleted after issuing: git reset --hard HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621424/all-staged-but-uncommitted-files-deleted-after-issuing-git-reset-hard-head)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+recover+uncommitted+files

Answer (score 0):

You may to be able to retrieve contents of the deleted files with `git fsck` and `git show`.  See the following example - we create a new
repository, create a new file, add it to the index, then run `git rm`:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ja/so/git-rm/.git/
$ echo hello > FILE
$ git add FILE
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   FILE

$ git rm -r -f ./
rm 'FILE'
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Our `FILE` is now lost:

```
$ ls -Al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 7 ja users 4096 Mar 12 16:17 .git
```

Let's try to retrieve its contents with `git fsck` and `git show`:

```
$ git fsck
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
dangling blob ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a
$ git show ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a
hello
```

Comment: It's okay I didn't lost much and already redid the work really quick. (My keyboard is actually on fire right now). But thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to undo "rm -r -f" command. Never use rm -f command if you don't commits the changes. without -f option git rm check uncommitted files.

Comment: This is not correct. If the object had been added to index, it's already in git's object DB.... as dangling objects, at the very least.

Comment: Is there any way to repair deleted files after git rm -r -f command?

Comment: Well.... sure: `git reset --hard` just to get back to the last revision :-). But I guess you mean to get the new files or modified files? You don't actually repair them. Once you identify the object that you care about, you can run `git cat-file -p object-id > some-file.txt`.... and hell, I hope we are talking about a handful of files and not dozens over dozens.